# Reserve static IP address for k8s external service

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to reserve static IP address for my k8s exposed service.
If I am not mistaken when I expose the k8s service it gets the random public IP address. I redeploy my app often and the IP changes.
But I want to get permanent public IP address.
My task is to get my application via permanent IP address (or DNS-name).

Answer (score 4):

This is cloud provider specific, but from the tag on your question it appears you are using Google Cloud Platform's Kubernetes Engine (GKE). My answer is specific for this situation.

From the [Setting up HTTP Load Balancing with Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#step_5_optional_configuring_a_static_ip_address) tutorial:

> ```
> gcloud compute addresses create web-static-ip --global
> ```

And in your Ingress manifest:

> ```
> apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
> kind: Ingress
> metadata:
>   name: basic-ingress
>   annotations:
>     kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "web-static-ip"
> spec:
>   backend:
>     serviceName: web
>     servicePort: 8080
> ```

You can do something similar if you using [Service instead of Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: helloweb
  labels:
    app: hello
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: "web-static-ip"
  selector:
    app: hello
    tier: web
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
```

Comment: Thanks! The link https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip helps me to resolve my issue!